# find closure, interior, and derived sets with respect to topologies

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have a midterm coming up and I'm trying to understand this problem. I understand what closure and interior mean but the different topologies are a little confusing to me.

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the set of real numbers and $A= \{ x: x \mathrm{\, is \, rational \}}$.

Find the closure, interior, and derived sets of $A$ with respect to the discrete topology, the indiscrete topology and the topology formed by defining a set to be open if it contains all but at most countably many points

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: In the discrete topology, every subset of $\Bbb R$ is both closed and open. In the indiscrete topology, only the empty set and all of $\Bbb R$ are open (or closed). In the cocountable topology (the typical name for that last one), note that the closed subsets of $\Bbb R$ are $\Bbb R$ itself, and every at most countable subset of $\Bbb R.$

A few useful results that may help you with this problem (and are good exercises to prove) are the following:

- The closure of $A$ is the smallest closed set $C$ such that $A\subseteq C$. In particular, then, $A$ is closed if and only if it is equal to its closure.
- The interior of $A$ is the largest open set $U$ such that $U\subseteq A.$ In particular, then, $A$ is open if and only if it is equal to its interior.

Comment: since discrete referes to the set being both open and closure, would I then assume that the closure is the set, the interior would also be the set since if you make the neighborhood small enough there will always be a point in the set and im not sure what they mean by the derived sets of A? @CameronBuie

Comment: [derived set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_%28mathematics%29)

Comment: @Kathryn: You're exactly right on the first two counts, but your reasoning is a bit shaky. (I will expand my answer to give an alternative approach.) The derived set of $A$ is the set of limit points of $A$--those points $x\in\Bbb R$ such that for any neighborhood $U$ of $x,$ $U$ contains a point of $A$ that is distinct from $x$. Put another way, a point $x\in\Bbb R$ is *not* in the derived set of $A$ if and only if there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U$ contains at most one point of $A$. Points in the derived set of $A$ may or may not be points of $A$.

Comment: @CameronBuie   ok, so limit points are kind of like accumulation points?

Comment: @Kathryn: Yes, many texts use the terms interchangeably. Did my additions to the answer make things any clearer/easier for you?

Comment: @CameronBuie  I believe that all of my definitions are starting to blur at this point but the closure, interior and limit points are different considering which topology that we are referring to. The question first asks with respect to discrete topology, which leads me to believe that the closure is R, the interior is empty, and that there is a limit pt at every x. For indiscrete topology, considering that R is open, the closure is R, the interior is the set, and every x is a limit point. With respect to cocountable topology, the closure is R, the intrior is empty and ???? on the limit pts.

Comment: @Kathryn: Probably the best approach here is to know exactly what the open and closed sets are in each topology. The interior of $A$ is the largest open set contained in $A$, and the closure of $A$ is the smallest open set containing $A$. For two of the topologies, there is **exactly one** open set contained in $A$, so interior is easy. In one topology, there is **exactly one** closed set containing $A$, so closure is easy. In two of the topologies, $A$ is closed, and so equal to its closure. In one topology, $A$ is open, and so equal to its interior. ...

Comment: ... Are you aware that finite and countable subsets of $\Bbb R$ have *uncountable* complements? This fact will be necessary to find the interior in one instance. Now, let's talk about the derived set. Recall that a point $x$ will *not* be in the derived set of $A$ if and only if there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ containing at most one point of $A$. Take any $x\in\Bbb R$. In each case, try to find (or show that there isn't) such a neighborhood $U$ of $x$. Note that every subset of $\Bbb R$ is open in the discrete topology, $\Bbb R$ is the only non-empty open set in the indiscrete topology, ...

Comment: ... and any subset of $\Bbb R$ with a countable complement is open in the cocountable topology. You may need to do $2$ cases with the cocountable topology, depending on whether $x\in A$ or $x\notin A$.